# Why is my while loop being ignored inside of this function?

Tags: python

So, I've written a function that is meant to take a password, userID, and pin, match it to an account(in the prewritten dictionary) and validate it, but if three wrong info is inputted, it shall end the while loop. However, after i input the password, user ID and pin, it just stops with exit code 0. Can anyone explain why?

```
info = {"password0": "FelixIscool3103",
    "PIN0": "3456",
    "UserID0": "Felixx",
    "password1": "JohnSmith348",
    "PIN1": "7845",
    "UserID1": "JohnSmithy99"}


def checker(password, user_id, pin, strike_pass, strike_id, strike_pin):
    while strike_id and strike_pass and strike_pin != 3:
        for i in range(0, len(info), 3):
            if password == info["password"+str(i)]:
                return print("Correct password")
            break
        else:
            strike_pass + 1
            return print("Password is incorrect")


        for x in range(2, len(info), 3):
            if user_id == info["UserID"+str(i)]:
                return print("Correct user ID")
            break
        else:
            strike_id + 1
            return print("Wrong user ID")


        for y in range(1, len(info), 3):
            if pin == info["PIN" + str(i)]:
                return print("Correct user ID")
            break
        else:
            strike_pin + 1
            return print("PIN incorrect")



checker(input("Enter your password"),
        input("Enter your user ID"),
        input("Enter your pin"),
        0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: The `while` condition requires `strike_id` to be true-ish, but you're passing a value of `0` when calling `checker()`.

Comment: All the `return print(...)` lines make 0 sense.

Comment: Keeping in mind that you should never store passwords in plain text for any *actual* use... your dictionary would make more sense with the usernames as keys and the passwords as their corresponding values. You also don't really need any of those for loops.

Comment: ...And why check the password before even checking the username?

Answer (score 3):

The numeric value `0` is "falsey" in Python.  And you're passing a `0` for `strike_id` and `strike_pass`.  So the `while` condition is evaluating to:

```
while False and False and True:
```

Which is, of course, `false`.

It *looks like* your intent was to compare each of those values to `3`, but you only compared one of them:

```
while strike_id != 3 and strike_pass != 3 and strike_pin != 3:
```

Comment: Or (perhaps less clearly) `while 3 not in (strike_id, strike_pass, strike_pin):`

Comment: @Fexel if you feel like this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark. Accepts and upvotes (you'll be able to upvote soon) are how we say thank you here. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

The while loop continues while the condition is True.
As `strike_id and strike_pass and strike_pin != 3` is False it never enters the while loop.

I am not really sure what the statement should check, but maybe try:

```
limit = 3
while all((strike_id <=limit, strike_pass <= limit, strike_pin <= limit)):
```

However, make sure the strikes get added correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure this use of `all()` is idiomatic (but I could be out of date on my idioms).  Generally `all()` is applied to an already existing iterable or to a generator expression. I think using a couple of `and`s would be more readable (as shown in @David's answer).